# In what cases CPU direct transfer works faster than DMA? In what cases DMA transfer works faster than CPU direct transfer?

Tags: dma

I'm a little bit confused about the cases in which CPU can direct transfer the data faster than DMA(Direct Memory Access Controller)? and vice-versa?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1 - CPU faster than DMA

> CPU is idle. No task is running except yours (or your task has highest priority and the scheduling is priority scheduling) and Core interrupt is disabled (This will even stop the scheduling as there will be no timer tick interrupt). In that case, cpu transfer will be definitely faster than DMA as generally CPU gets faster clock than the Bus(AHB in ARM) clock which provides clock to DMA.

2 - DMA faster than CPU

> In Normal system where there are always a few process running and interrupts are enabled which can cause delay as CPU will be running ISR frequently and will be jumping process context due to scheduling.

Comment: Thank you Shaibal!

I also found another answer: CPU is faster than DMA when data is transferred in between internal registers. This case doesn't require DMA to take over the control on bus and bypass CPU.

Comment: What do you mean by internal registers?

Comment: I mean there is a data transfer which doesn't involve memory but registers like general purpose registers. That could be the case.

Comment: General purpose registers? As in the Processor's internal general purpose registers like in ARM R0, R1, etc? 
In that case DMA will not be able to access those registers at all. Those are CPU's internal registers. If you are talking about MMIO peripheral registers, then I do not think CPU will always be faster than the DMA. Its possible that the thread which is doing the copy gets scheduled out of the queue. Maybe you can disable the global CPU interrupt before copy starts and then enable it when copy is done. In that case CPU can be faster than DMA.